# visible callout in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am preparing my presentation in Beamer. I am trying to keep the call out stays visible on the slide. I don't want it to pops-up on my click. What option i need to activate in my tikz node?

some texts where the call out stars.\tikz[remember picture] \node (a) {\vphantom{X}};}

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<2> (a.east) ++(-0.5,0.5) node[anchor=west,ellipse callout,fill=red!50,opacity=.8, yshift=.8cm, callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)}] {tex.stackexchange};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: see, if `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<2-> (a.east) ++(-0.5,0.5) node[anchor=west,ellipse callout,fill=red!50,opacity=.8, yshift=.8cm, callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)}] {tex.stackexchange};
\end{tikzpicture}` do, what you like to have. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: thank you for your comment. but, It didn't work! You have to press any anykey for this to appear. I don't want a pop up call out. just a fix callout box staying on the slide.

Comment: Remove `<2>` ??

Comment: @user459806, your question is not very clear, without context i can only guessing what you like to have. sorry, my crystal ball is on vacation  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- only code snippet without of context of mostly doesn't enable to help you. we haven't *crystal balls* that we would be able to see its use or your document (many problems source is in document preamble) and then help you ...
- so i only suspect, that this can be solution of your problem.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<1-> (a.east) ++(-0.5,0.5) node[anchor=west,ellipse callout,
                                     fill=red!50,opacity=.8, yshift=.8cm, 
                                     callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)}] {tex.stackexchange};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(note `-` in `\path<1->`

- i can't test above proposition, so do this for me and let me know, if your problem is solved with it
- anyway, please complete your code snippet to complete but small document beginning with `\docutmentclas{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and only for your problem relevant loaded packages in preamble

Comment: This also working fine. @smartcarter suggested to remove <2> which is working as well. Thank you indeed.

Comment: anyway, please from code snipped complete small document. this will help many members of site :)